# Comment conflict in HQL grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am trying to create the `--i;` statement.

But my problem lies with the **single line comment rule** of HQL which states:

```
 L_S_COMMENT : ('--' | '//')  .*? '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN)  ;
```

I wrote the rules in the *lexer*:

```
T_SUB2         : '--' ;
T_SEMICOLON    : ';' ;
```

Rule in *parser*:

```
dummy_rule: T_SUB2 'i' T_SEMICOLON ;
```

When i test the rule it works fine with the parse tree correctly displayed, **But** when i press *ENTER* for a new line it shows an error, And it wont accept any more rules, I know its the `L_S_COMMENT` rule because when i remove it the rules works fine.

But deleting it is not the optimal solution any ideas what might cause this and how to bypass it.

Comment: Your grammar seems to contradict itself. Informally, when is `--` a start of a comment, and when is it not?

Comment: that's why i asked how to skip this contradict without removing the comment rule

Comment: @Makdous: That's not a grammar question. It's a language-design question. How would **you** decide whether a comment was a comment or a `--` statement when you look at it? You have to answer that question first, and then you can design a grammar to fit. Personally, I think having to answer that question indicates that adding `--f` as a statement is not a good idea. After all, `f -= 1` is hardly any harder to type, and a lot less confusing to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relevant statements always have to be terminated in a SEMI, then effectively exclude then from the comment definition:

```
COMMENT 
    : ( CMark .*? Vws 
      | DMark .*? ~[; \t\r\n\f] Hws* Vws 
      ) -> channel(HIDDEN)  
    ;

fragment CMark : '//' ;
fragment DMark : '--' ;
fragment Hws   : [ \t] ;
fragment Vws   : [\r\n]+ ;
```

*Explanation*

The first alt of the rule matches a standard `//` comment

The second alt will match a `--` comment iff the one visible character immediately prior to the terminating whitespace is not a SEMI. The `~` is set negation, while `[; \t\r\n\f]` is a set of characters. Since there is no operator modifying the set, `~[; \t\r\n\f]` will match only a single character that is not one of the named characters.

Hence, the comment rule will not match the terminal portion of a line of code that contains `--` and terminates in a SEMI.

Comment: Can you explain what this rule does?